# how to convert SQL select statement to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

Hi i'm new to SQL and LINQ and i need to convert this sql statement to LINQ

```
select r.*, 
(Select name From org_table where org_ID= r.org_ID )org
(Select name From Depart_table where Depart_ID= r.Depart_ID)depart
from reserve_table r 
where name like '
```

Comment: is your `where name like` statement incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
var result = from r in reserve_table
             where r.name.Contains("something")
             select new {
                          org = (from o in org_table where o.Org_ID = r.Org_ID select o.name)
                          depart = (from d in Depart_table where d.Depart_ID = r.Depart_ID select d.name)
                          // add the rest
                        }
```